# Change resolution on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have my Raspi 3 connected with an HDMI cable, but the picture is totally blurred. The screen is a 4k screen from AOC. I tried to change the resulution in the /boot/config.txt file, but it didn't helped. Also after I rebooted the Raspi I couldn't open the config.txt file again.

EDIT:
I tried the steps from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891235/how-to-change-screen-resolution-of-raspberry-pi

Comment: You need to provide details about how you "tried to change the resulution in the /boot/config.txt" and in what context you "couldn't open the config.txt file again".

Comment: You should probably try [`xrandr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure what what values you should put into `/boot/config.txt` under `hdmi_mode` and `hdmi_group` you can first try different values with `tvservice`.

You should use `tvservice -m DMT` and `tvservice -m CEA` to get a list of available modes.

Next try using `--explicit="GROUP MODE DRIVE"` to set the chosen values.
Example: `tvservice --explicit="DMT 81 HDMI"` to set it to *mode 81: 1366x768 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:85MHz progressive*

Another thing you can try is to enable only the "safe mode" by uncommenting only `hdmi_safe=1` in `/boot/config.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The following link has all of the settings for the RPi's config.txt file.  There is a section dedicated to the display settings that might help.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Also, you can modify the config.txt file from any PC or Mac by using an SD card reader.  You can locate the file on the SD card (/boot/config.txt), modify it then reinsert the SD card in to the RPi.